# How to surround selected code with multiline comment signs in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'd like to select a portion of code and command the IDE to put `/*` before it and `*/` after it quickly. This options seems missing from the "Surround with..." tool. Where can I find this option or how exactly can I add it?

Comment: On windows the keyboard shortcut for toggling block comments is `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `/`. You can view/change it from `File` -> `Settings` -> `Keymap` -> `Main menu` -> `Code` -> `Comment with block comment`

Comment: @Morfic thank you, this is the answer. Please post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are already 2 key bindings for comment toggling. On windows the shortcuts are:

- comment with line comment: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>

```java
// String myString;
// myString = "something";
```

- comment with block comment <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>

```java
/* String myString;
   myString = "something"; */
```

You can view a/o change them from `File` => `Settings` => `Keymap` => `Main menu` => `Code` => `Comment with Line comment` & `Comment with Block comment`

[image: comment keymap]